# Regular expression search support in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

We are trying to create an editor environment as like a Ms-Word. Please let us know the following points are possible using CKEditor.

1. Is it possible to do the Find/Replace option using wildcards or regular expression feature in CKEditor as like Ms-Word environment.
2. Is it possible to import word documents into the CKEditor with all the formatting.

Looking forward your help.

Answer (score 0):

sadly it's not evident which programming language you use.
ckeditor is availible as java library and for webpages. I will suppose that you want to use it as a wysiwyg editor on your homepage.

1) There are some Plugins for ckeditor that support this features. Please take a look at the official homepage.

2) Not as easy as you wish. The simplest was to do that is:
- convert the doc/docx file to a html file
- import that html file

If you want that your clients could upload a word file and work with it in your editor your best chance is to use the googledocs api to convert your word file to a html file and then use it in your editor.

That's the only way I know.

Comment: We are using Javascript and jQuery languages to create a CKEditor plugins.